# A table with 2 fields with different data types, only one of them is for join purpose, is this a good solution?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am designing a simple dictionary database with relational database. There is one table to store all the English words, naming `WordEn`, with an *integer id* as the *primary key*. Then there is another table, naming `ExplanationEn`, storing the explanations of all the English words in different languages from English, e.g. Chinese, Japanese etc. In my first plan, the `ExplanationEn` table contains the following columns:

- `wordId` -- the foreign key referencing to the primary key of `WordEn`
- `language` -- in which language is the explanation
- `explanation` -- the explanation in given language (with a String - `varchar` data type)

The relationship between the `WordEn` and `ExplanationEn` is *one-to-many* as a word can definitely have many meanings

**But considering lots of English words might have a corresponding word in another language, I plan to create another table, e.g. `WordCh` storing the Chinese words** So I would like to still make use of the `ExplanationEn` to bridge the `WordEn` and `WordCh`. Two solutions came into my mind:

1. keep the structure of the `ExplanationEn` table unchanged, then when the `ExplanationEn` `join` the `WordCh`, the condition can *cast* the explanation to an *integer* and compare with the `WordCh.id` **The cost of the cast will be on each record of the `ExplanationEn` table**
2. add a new field, e.g. called `counterPartId`, as the foreign key of the `WordCh` to `ExplanationEn`. As a result, each record of the `ExplanationEn` will contain either `WordCh` or `ExplanationEn` field empty, meaning it is impossible for both fields filled with values. Comparing with the first solution, it does now have the cost of *cast* string value to integer, but an extra field is added instead

**Question: Which is better solution among these two, or are there any other better solution?**

Comment: Has each english word only one explanation in a certain language? Or can have more explanations due to a molteplicity of meaning? For each word in english, there is only another word in another language? Or there can be multiple words?

Comment: @Renzo Good catch :) But in this question I just assumed the one-to-one relationship to simplify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each english word has only one explanation in another language, and that *can* have at most another corresponding word in that language, I think a good solution can be the addition of a new field to the `ExplanationEx` table that contains the corresponding word in the language the explanation is given. This new field, (for instance `translation`), can have a null value.

With this solution you can reduce the number of joins used to retrieve the information you need.

Comment: Thanks really much :) Your explanation of reducing the number of joins is a great reminder to me. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: reducing joins is definitely not a goal!

Answer (score -1):

I would work with 3 tables:
**Words** (word, wordId, language)
**Meanings** (wordId, meaning, meaningId)
**Translatesv1** (fromMeaningId, toMeaningId)   -- self join table
or
**Translatesv2** (groupId, meaningId)    -- self join table

Cardinalities:
1 Word in 1 language may have several Meanings
Meanings need a self join table.

The idea is to have a self join between Meanings, NOT between Words, and to generalize so you don't have to change the db structure every time you include a new language.
Translatev1 has the drawback that it has an implied 'from..to' direction.
Tranlastev2 is a bit more complex to implement but is more flexible and works in any direction.

Comment: A word has meaning, i.e. explanation. On the other hand, it might have corresponding word, i.e. translation. In your design there is only meaning

Comment: one word can have different meanings. And the translattion depends on the meaning rather than the word !

Comment: I didn't understand you fully yet. Take an example word - [get](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/get), it has two meanings: 1. to receive or come to have possession ... 2. to cause to be in one's possession or succeed in .... Take your TranslatesV1 as an example, fromMeaningId can be the first meaning, and toMeaningId can be the second meaning? Sorry that I am not able vote back due to tech constraint. I am also curious about how to stop the self join, according to my understanding if a word has 10 meanings, we need 10 times self join. please rectify if I misunderstand

Comment: as to your second solution candidate, I don't understand the use of groupid, isn't it the word ID?